# The app references non-public selectors with Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, xcode5

Today, I submit my app to iTunes by App Loader but i get an warning: 
The application loader reports:
The app references non-public selectors in id
This warning can result in your app being rejected for using private APIs.

But I did not pay attention and still submit my app to iTunes.
Now I know that the obtaining the id facebook caused that warning.

I need reject the binary file and resubmit. But my app is still in a state "Upload received". I don't know how to solve this problem. Please help me. Thank in advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a Facebook support issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wait a few minutes until the status clears. Then reject it under "Binary Details" in iTunesConnect.

Most likely iTunesConnect cannot flag it for waiting for review until some processing is done, worst case a manual action by Apple is done (with regards to the warning). Not much you can do.

Comment: Thank you, I will wait until tomorrow

Comment: Great! Did it get solved?

Comment: Hint: Approve the answer ;)